# Remembering last scroll position on a HTML document for reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something called "Course Reader". It is a big HTML document that can contain text, images, youtube videos, soundcloud audio and so on. Most of the stuff is imported from external sources like EPUB documents, so I don't have much control of the HTML and how it's is generated. I need to create the ability to remember the last position on the document where the user was, so when the next time the document is loaded (maybe it won't be the same browser or the same device), I can take the user to that position.

One thing that I thought would work was this: get the current top position with $(window).scrollTop(), but since that would be different for different browsers, I thought I would save that value as a percentage of the whole document height. So, if at the moment I'm at 45% of the document, on the next load I get the 45%, recalculate how much that is in pixels of the current document height and scroll there. But, this is not a solution, since it won't even work the same in Chrome and Firefox.

What is important is that the user once may open the document from a desktop browser and the next time from mobile or tablet and I still need to move them to their last saved position.

I tired a few other things not worth mentioning here and I'm out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if each section of the page was uniquely identified (even if by just integers). Store the section they were previously at on their account, and then when they visit the page again if that number exists, go to that section.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to wrap each item in a div/section with an ID? In that case you can just remember the ID with localStorage, and when you come back, you read it and use a window.location.hash to go to the ID (anchor link).

Comment: @tony.gustafsson I have, but only individual sections. There may be a few pages of text inside some section (with a ID), but I don't have control of the HTML inside that section.

Comment: `What is important is that the user once may open the document from a desktop browser and the next time from mobile or tablet and I still need to move them to their last saved position.` Then you have to handle it server side and use some way to authenticate user, as a login logic or IP

Comment: @A.Wolff authentication exist, that is not the issue here.

Comment: If you don't have control over the DOM, yet you wan't your app to remember things about the content of the DOM, then you're not going to have a good time. Maybe you can inject splitters in between each section, assign those splitters a unique Id, and use those for caching off where to load back to the next time the user visits.

Comment: I liked your idea of using a percentage of the whole page content. It is quite simple. Of course it is not perfect as each element may not render exactly the same on all devices, so percentages would be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you do not have control on the HTML and how it is generated, but if in the end you have a plain HTML document, and you can use JavaScript (even more simple with jQuery that you have tagged in your question), you can still re-factor it on client side by manipulating the DOM.

You should be able to walk through the DOM, insert hidden anchors here and there (e.g. every couple of words), and detect the upper-most anchor within the screen at each user scroll, so that you can record that anchor as "last viewed user position".

Of course your method of insertion must be consistent and reproducible on all devices, so that it re-factors the DOM exactly the same way, and the anchors are placed in the exact same position every time. So do not use random ids for anchors. E.g. you could use a prefixed counter, and just need to make sure it does not collide with pre-existing id's.